# Swift Compile Error - Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting this error on my Swift iOs app when I try to compile:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "checkForiOS14 #1 () -> Swift.Bool in App_Clip.NoteView.(reminderSymbolName in _82CBB329F1D225F83535F59E6FD7F4C3).getter : Swift.String", referenced from:
      App_Clip.NoteView.(reminderSymbolName in _82CBB329F1D225F83535F59E6FD7F4C3).getter : Swift.String in NoteView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The property it is referring to is a computed property/private var in a view to check the version of iOS:

```
private var iosVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion

private var reminderSymbolName: String {
        if checkForiOS14() {
            return "checkmark.circle"
        } else {
            return "checklist"
        }
        
        func checkForiOS14() -> Bool {
            if let version = Double(iosVersion) {
                if version <= 14.9 {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return false
        }

    }
```

I have done all the basic stuff, deleting derived data, cleaning my build folder, restarted my mac, I even went back to a commit that builds and copied the changed files to the new commit, but this error will not go away. I am not using any pods, but I am using some SPM packages. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's built-in availability checks you can use for this purpose:

```
private var reminderSymbolName: String {
    if #available(iOS 14.9, *) {
        return "checkmark.circle"
    } else {
        return "checklist"
    }
}
```

See https://nshipster.com/available/

Comment: this is a much better way to do this than I was doing. Thank you for the tip :)

Comment: @BenjaminB. Glad to help! If this answers your question, hit the check mark on the left

Comment: It doesn't fix the "why didn't this compile" problem of the original question, but I did give it an upvote since it's a good idea and relevant here.

Comment: @BenjaminB. Are you sure there isn't some detail missing from the code snippet in your original question? I don't see why that code would lead to a linker error.

Comment: not really...this was the only part of my code that changed...

Answer (score 0):

Well, isn't that always how it goes? You try everything, post on Stack, and then literally minutes later you fix it?  Apparently the answer was taking my method out of the computed property and making it private, like so:

```
 private func checkForiOS14() -> Bool {
        if let version = Double(iosVersion) {
            if version <= 14.9 {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    private var reminderSymbolName: String {
        if checkForiOS14() {
            return "checkmark.circle"
        } else {
            return "checklist"
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you if you are stuck like I was...

Comment: That inner `if` statement reduces to just `return version <= 14.9`.